# SFML C++11 can't call the function twice from two different objects of the same type

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object, sfml

I am trying to create two RedShip objects. Each of them has a bullets_.create() command which initializes a Bullet object in an array of Bullet objects. I have another similar object called GreenShip. When I instantiate 1 GreenShip and 1 RedShip they both can initialize seperate Bullet objects into the bullets_[] array. But when i have the same object twice only one of them is able to create the Bullet objects even though when debugged they both call the create() method succesfully.

Here is the problematic code:

```
the ObjectPool class:

class BulletPool{
public:
    BulletPool();
    void create(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius, bool enemy, float velx, float vely);
    void update(sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Vector2f screen);

private:
    Bullet* firstAvailable_;
    static const int POOL_SIZE = 100;
    Bullet bullets_[POOL_SIZE];
};
```

the BulletPool object constructor:

```
BulletPool::BulletPool() {
  // The first one is available.
  firstAvailable_ = &bullets_[0];

  // Each particle points to the next. all linked!!
  for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE - 1; i++)
  {
    bullets_[i].setNext(&bullets_[i + 1]);
  }

  // The last one terminates the list.
  bullets_[POOL_SIZE - 1].setNext(NULL);
}
```

BulletPool update method:

```
void BulletPool::update(sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Vector2f screen) {
    for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {
        bullets_[i].update(screen);
        if (!bullets_[i].inUse) {
            printf("foundavailable:%i\n",i);
            bullets_[i].setNext(firstAvailable_);
            firstAvailable_ = &bullets_[i];
            break;
        } else {
            std::printf("drawn::%i!\n",i);
            window.draw(bullets_[i].shape);
        }
    }
}
```

BulletPool.create() which takes in the arguments to be passed to the actual Bullet.init() which initializes the object. The BulletPool.create() is only responsible for placing the new object into the array:

```
void BulletPool::create(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color color, float bullet_radius, bool enemy, float velx, float vely) {

    assert(firstAvailable_ != NULL);

    printf("new bullet\n");
    Bullet* newBullet = firstAvailable_;
    firstAvailable_ = newBullet->getNext();

    newBullet->init(pos,color,bullet_radius,enemy,velx,vely);
    newBullet->inUse=true;


    return;
}
```

Each RedShip object tries to create a Bullet object periodically:

```
void RedShip::update(int base_time, BulletPool bullets) {
    if(base_time%40==0) {
        printf("red fire\n");
        bullets.create({shape.getPosition().x, shape.getPosition().y + shape.getLocalBounds().height/2}, sf::Color::Red, 4,true, 0,3);
    }
}
```

the console result:

```
drawn::0!
drawn::1!
foundavailable:2
red fire
new bullet
red fire
new bullet
drawn::0!
drawn::1!
drawn::2!
It should draw 1 more since i am trying to initialize 2 objects.
```

The Bullet object also has these components as default:

```
Bullet* getNext() const { return state_.next_; } //to get the next Bullet object in BulletPool
void setNext(Bullet* next) { state_.next_ = next; } //to set the next object
bool inUse{false}; //is the object active?
```

## **EDIT**

I tried updating the BulletPool after running the create function but have discovered that the first time the method is called, the object is not being initialized into the array. The firstAvaliable stays the same.

```
foundavailable:4
red fire
new bullet
foundavailable:4
red fire
new bullet
foundavailable:5
```

Comment: "only one of them is able to create the Bullet objects" Please explain how you arrived to this conclusion. What exactly have you observed?

Comment: It appears as though only one of them is able to create the Bullet object as there is only 1 being drawn on screen and only 1  being added to the array. Both objects call the function bullets.create() however when trying to get the index of the drawn objects in the update method of BulletPool (as seen in the console output)  it only returns 1 more object. However the create() method was called twice?

Comment: `Bullet* newBullet = firstAvailable_; firstAvailable_ = newBullet->getNext();` What do getNext() returns ? Also, I honestly would use an int for firstAvailable and increment it instead of your pointer arithmetics.

Comment: getNext() returns a pointer that is pointing to the object after newBullet. And can you explain how one would use firstAvailable as an int. Do you mean to use it as an index to quickly scroll through?

Comment: @Zouch **ALRIGHT FOUND SOMETHING BUT  I DONT KNOW HOW TO FIX IT!** You will notice that i was using a base_time integer to manage the delays between the calls to the create method. I found out that if i set it up so that each object fired at a different time they worked. Does anyone know a way to call a function periodically.

Comment: Test against a timer in your main loop, if you have reached the required time just call the function.

Comment: @Zouch i know thats what i am doing inmy code but when two object do something at the same timeit doesnt work

Comment: And also if i was to just test against a timer it would not do things periodically it would only do things once until the next loop of the timer. Therefore i used modulo to test against it.